# Scan with Nikto using specific interface

Tags: nikto

I have a virtual attack server that I've thrown 10 nics on so I can run multiple scans in tandem without interfering with each other. I haven't been able to find it, but does Nikto have a way to choose a specific interface to scan from? nmap has `-e eth1` for example. I was curious if Nikto had something similar.

Comment: If it's not in the documentation ... https://github.com/sullo/nikto/wiki/Annotated-Option-List

Comment: @schroeder the main Github page still includes the msf+ option under format, which I believe was removed in 2019, so I didn't know how current that was.

Comment: If you need such an option but the software does not support it, you could adapt your **routing table**, or run the application inside a Linux **namespace**, which can provide additional benefits in terms of isolation. Inside that namespace you only expose one NIC, and it will become the default route.